# If statement run code despite being false

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm very new to Python and to test my knowledge, I'm trying to build a Black Jack game. The code is rather long at this points, everything works fine, the following code is the only problem:

```
def player_round_end():
    global player_points
    if player_points_one == player_points_two:   
        # This works just fine
    elif player_points_one != player_points_two:
        print(f"---{player_points_one} or {player_points_two}")
        if player_points_one or player_points_two == 21: #This is the probelem
            print("---Black Jack!")

            if player_points_one == 21:
                player_points = player_points_one
            else:
                player_points = player_points_two

            print(f"Player points: {player_points}")
            dealer()      
        elif player_points_one and player_points_two > 21:
            print("You lost!")
            new_game()
```

I added some print functions so that I could easier find the bug. The problem with the == 21 statement is that it is sometimes defined as true, despite not beging true.

Example output from CMD:

```
---1 or 11
---Black Jack!
---Player points: 11
```

I drew and an A, which means that I have either 1 or 11 points. IT corectly defines that these are not equal, but it then defines that one of these is equal to 21, why is that? Let me know if you need more information or need to see all the code (though its not very pretty).

Comment: if player_points_one  == 21 or player_points_two == 21?

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if player_points_one or player_points_two == 21: ## Meaning player_points_one exists or player_points_two == 21

if player_points_one == 21 or player_points_two == 21: ## Correct solution
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thank you! As far as I remember, the first statement would be correct in VBA but it obviously doesn't work in Python.

Comment: if its right, please feel free to select it as correct answer to close this question :)

Comment: I will!. But there is a 10 min timer from the post is created until I can pick the right solution :)

Comment: @DennisChristiansen why this answer got unaccepted if it worked

Comment: I don't know, I didn't do anything? As far as I remember I did give credit to you for being the first with the right answer?

Comment: may be a bug; because it showed my answer was unaccepted and down voted #StrangeBug

Answer (score 2):

`player_points_one`, being a non-zero number, is resolving to `true`.

This statement may make intuitive sense to a human reader:

```
if player_points_one or player_points_two == 21
```

But programming is a bit more explicit than human intuition.  The conditions you're checking here are precisely:

- player_points_one
- player_points_two == 21

Whereas the conditions you want are:

- player_points_one == 21
- player_points_two == 21

Which would be:

```
if player_points_one == 21 or player_points_two == 21
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes sense! As I mentioned above, I'm completely new to Python, but in VBA you can actually do both, so I just assumed it worked the same way in Python.

Comment: @DennisChristiansen never assume that anything works the same way as VBA ;-)